# Build wheels outside of Debian

Tags: debian, lxml, python-wheel, debian-stretch

Looking for some expertise.

I am trying to build lxml 4.3.2 on a BeagleBone Black (small IoT device) that runs Debian 9.5.  I have previously `apt install`'d a lot of packages to make sure it can install.

It starts `Building wheels for collected packages: lxml`.  This continues for hours, and then crashes with the error `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)`.  I think this means the compiler ran out of memory.

I am looking to build the wheel for `lxml` outside of the BeagleBone Black.  Do you have suggestions on how to do this?  My personal machine is MacOS.

Comment: A container (like Docker) or a virtual machine (like VirtualBox) emulating this processor architecture.

Comment: [Docker with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc6 cross-compiler](https://github.com/zcsevcik/docker-raspberrypi), and [another one](https://github.com/yasuyuky/docker-rust-arm). Jsut for example.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64